# Missing logs and delay in logs when using BlobStorageRotatingFileHandler

Tags: python, azure, logging, flask, azure-storage

I have a flask API hosted on Azure and I am using azure_storage_logging.handlers package to send API runtime logs to Azure Storage. I am using BlobStorageRotatingFileHandler for it.
I receive few logs in my storage account. However, a huge number of logs are missing. My API is very CPU intensive.
Please let me know how to solve this problem.

```
def fun_logging(id, logfilename , loggername):
    mystorageaccountname = STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME
    mystorageaccountkey = STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY
    mystoragecontainer = STORAGE_CONTAINER
    utctime = asctime(gmtime())    
    logger = logging.getLogger(loggername)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    log_formater = logging.Formatter('%(utctime)s - %(id)s  - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    azure_blob_handler = BlobStorageRotatingFileHandler(filename = logfilename, account_name=mystorageaccountname,account_key=mystorageaccountkey, delay=False, maxBytes= 10000,container=mystoragecontainer)
    azure_blob_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    azure_blob_handler.setFormatter(log_formater)
    if (logger.hasHandlers()):
        logger.handlers.clear()
    logger.addHandler(azure_blob_handler)
    logger = logging.LoggerAdapter(logger, {'id': id, 'utctime':utctime})
    return logger

####### Calling function
logger = fun_logging(id, 'Logs//xyz.log', 'xyz')
logger.info(Result.log) ## the variable I am logging
```

Answer (score 0):

I searched for `BlobStorageRotatingFileHandler` you used, and found the github repo [`michiya/azure-storage-logging`](https://github.com/michiya/azure-storage-logging). I'm not sure whether it was used in your flask project. If yes, I advise you to use `TableStorageHandler` for logging in your scenario for writing a huge number of logs, not using `BlobStorageRotatingFileHandler`.

After I reviewed the code of this repo, there is an issue to use BlockBlob to store an entire log file once, not to append a log record into an AppendBlob. So it's not suitable for your scenario with massive logs. And Azure recommends to use AppendBlob for logging, see below comes from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python#understand-the-sample-code) if using Blob Storage.

> Append blobs are used for logging, such as when you want to write to a
>   file and then keep adding more information. Most objects stored in
>   Blob storage are block blobs.

So you can try to use Append Blob via Azure Blob Storage SDK for Python for wrapping a logging API by your self. Otherwise, Azure Table Storage is a good choise which you can try for logging. For massive logs recording, the best practice is that to write logs into EventHubs, then to use other services like Stream Analysis to filter and transfer data into Blob Storage.

Hope it helps.